# Virtual Machine MAC Address or Host Operating System MAC Address?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, mac-address

Let's say I'm browsing from Ubuntu Virtual Machine using Firefox.

IF the website I am visiting can see the MAC Address, which MAC address will it see?

Is MAC Address of Ubuntu VM or MAC Address of the host Operating System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you are visiting can't see the MAC address of your computer, unless it is at the same LAN.

For a computer on the same LAN, it depends on your VM settings. Bridged access will see the MAC of the guest, while NAT access will see the MAC of the host.